# Cannot populate QTableWidget using .setItem(row, colum, QTableWidgetItem(data))

Tags: python, pyqt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I wanted to test PyQt to write a quick app to display and edit data in an Excel like form but the data is never shown.

Both the docs and the book I read say that using .setItem(row, colum, QTableWidgetItem(data)) on a QtableWidget object is **one** way to go.
However, the following code doesn't work, I only have an empty table and I can't figure out why. Any idea ?

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QTableWidget,
    QTableWidgetItem,
    QMenu,
    QAction,
    QInputDialog,
)


class SpreadsheetFramework(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setMinimumSize(1000, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle("Spreadsheet Table")
        # Used for copy and paste actions
        self.item_text = None
        self.createTable()
        self.fillTable()
        self.show()

    def createTable(self):
        self.table_widget = QTableWidget()

        self.table_widget.setRowCount(10)
        self.table_widget.setColumnCount(10)

        self.table_widget.setCurrentCell(0, 0)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.table_widget)

    def fillTable(self):
        for i in range(10):
            for j in range(10):
                self.table_widget.setItem(i, j, QTableWidgetItem(i * j))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = SpreadsheetFramework()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is what the window looks like when I run the code

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the data in a QTableWidgetItem and pass it through the constructor then it must be a string.

```py
self.table_widget.setItem(i, j, QTableWidgetItem(str(i * j)))
```

The downside is that it is no longer a number but a string that represents a number.

Another better option is to use setData to pass the number to the Qt.DisplayRole role.

```py
item = QTableWidgetItem()
item.setData(Qt.DisplayRole, i * j)
self.table_widget.setItem(i, j, item)
```

Comment: Both the methods you mention work for this simple exemple but it still doesn't in my real app. I must have made a mistake somewhere else. Thank you

Comment: @Alazeth I only solve the problem that you make in your post, that of *real app* is irrelevant for SO. I also recommend that you pass the [tour] so that you know what to do if someone solves your problem.